# Using GET and POST for PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I've written a PHP script to get data from a mysql database and convert this into JSON data. I can then display this on my webserver.

I want to JSON data to my Android Application. I understand I need to edit my PHP script to include GET and POST.

However, to send data to the application, should I be using GET or POST, or can I use either?

Security is not a concern here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between POST and GET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select the appropriate method for the task. As it seems that you just want to get (in opposite to store) some information, use GET.

> *HTTP defines methods (sometimes referred to as verbs) to indicate the desired action to be performed on the identified resource. ... Often, the resource corresponds to a file or the output of an executable residing on the server. ...*
>
> **GET**
>
> The GET method requests a representation of the specified
> resource. Requests using GET should only retrieve data and should have
> no other effect. (This is also true of some other HTTP methods.) ...
>
> **POST**
>
> The POST method requests that the server accept the entity
> enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the web resource
> identified by the URI. The data POSTed might be, for example, an
> annotation for existing resources; a message for a bulletin board,
> newsgroup, mailing list, or comment thread; a block of data that is
> the result of submitting a web form to a data-handling process; or an
> item to add to a database.
>
> **PUT**
>
> The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under
> the supplied URI. If the URI refers to an already existing resource,
> it is modified; if the URI does not point to an existing resource,
> then the server can create the resource with that URI.
>
> **DELETE**
>
> The DELETE method deletes the specified resource.
>
> **PATCH**
>
> The PATCH method applies partial modifications to a resource.

*Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods*

Answer (score 1):

If security is not a concern then you should use GET method